# Which is the correct Activity Type code for Netflix: 15 or 7? (Smart Home API)

Tags: logitech

The Smart Home API docs state that Netflix is 7 however I'm seeing Netflix coming up as 15 in real world tests.  Are the docs out of date and has 7 been deprecated or are there two different Netflix type codes for two different situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harmony recently migrated the "Watch Netflix" activity type to a "Watch Smart App" activity type that better scales as televisions introduce additional apps and capabilities. Our documentation has yet to be updated to reflect this. Watch Netflix activities created several months ago will continue to report as type 7; however newly created Netflix activities will now report as type 15.